# WSO2 / Mule vs OpenStack / CloudStack - what are the differences, similarities, benefits?

Tags: wso2, cloud, mule, openstack, apache-cloudstack

I've started my journey with cloud related technologies very recently. I'm trying to understand the basics as to be able to prepare the foundation for a basic cloud setup in my Internet of Things oriented company.

While browsing the Internet I've stumbled upon the following two groups of open source projects:

- WSO2 / Mule / ...
- OpenStack / CouldStack / Eucalyptus / ...

I'm trying to understand:

1. what kind of service do they offer? (IaaS, PaaS, SaaS, other?)
2. what are the differences between them?
3. what do they have in common?
4. how do the play with other cloud related technologies like Amazon AWS?
5. which one would you recommend to get some basic experience and for some early proof-of-concept? (I'm looking for the easiest option first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud stack and Open stack are open source softwares designed to manage, deploy virtual machines and networks which can deliver cloud services. Mainly these provide Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS). There are alot of comparisons on the internet on these two. So these softwares needs to be intalled on your hardware and maintain it and you provide a cloud service from it. When it comes Amazon AWS it is a readily available service where you don't do installations or maintain hardware, you just take service from them.

WSO2 and MuleSoft are different from above two and they are software platforms where several products(such as ESB). Both provide cloud platform facilities to deploye their products.

We cannot say which one to use but base on your requirements you may choose one or two (WSO2 products deployed on Amazon AWS or WSO2 products deployed on CloudStack VM's). Since you are willing to set up Internet of things, i think you may need to refer about products provided by above providers. Following source [1] will give you an idea about Iot platform  setup by several free open source WSO2 products.

[1] http://wso2.com/landing/internet-of-things/